# Licences & Limits not available under Data.com Administration

Tags: limits, data, licenses, data.com

Limits,Prospector Users,Prospector Preferences & Field Mapping are not available under Data.com administration in my prod org.

I found these in all other sandboxes and my Dev org too. Anything missing in this org.?

Is there anything which should be enabled to make these visible.
Kinldy let me know in case of any ideas.

Thanks in advance

[image]